# What is the best approach for serial data reception and processing using c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port

I am pretty new to coding with some experience in ASM and C for PIC. I am still learning high level programming with C#.

**Question**

I have a Serial port data reception and processing program in C#. To avoid losing data and knowing when it was coming, I set a *DataReceived* event and loop into the handling method until there were no more bytes to read.

When I attempted this, the loop continued endlessly and blocked my program from other tasks (such as processing the retrieved data) when I continuously received data.

I read about threading in C#, I created a thread that constantly checks for *SerialPort.Bytes2Read* property so it will know when to retrieve available data.

I created a second thread that can process data while new data is still being read. If bytes have been read and ReadSerial() has more bytes to read and the timeout (restarted every time a new byte is read from the serial) they can still be processed and the frames assembled via a method named DataProcessing() which reads from the same variable being filled by ReadSerial().

This gave me the desired results, but I noticed that with my solution (both *ReadSerial()* and *DataProcessing()* threads alive), CPU Usage was skyrocketed all the way to 100%!

How do you approach this problem without causing such high CPU usage?

```
public static void ReadSerial() //Method that handles Serial Reception
{
    while (KeepAlive) // Bool variable used to keep alive the thread. Turned to false
    {                 // when the program ends.
        if (Port.BytesToRead != 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) 
            {

             /* I Don't know any other way to 
                implement a timeout to wait for 
                additional characters so i took what 
                i knew from PIC Serial Data Handling. */

                if (Port.BytesToRead != 0)
                {
                    RxList.Add(Convert.ToByte(Port.ReadByte()));
                    i = 0;

                    if (RxList.Count > 20) // In case the method is stuck still reading
                        BufferReady = true; // signal the Data Processing thread to 
                 }                          // work with that chunk of data.

                 BufferReady = true; // signals the DataProcessing Method to work      
            }                        // with the current data in RxList.
        }         
    }    
}
```

Comment: Pic asm and C doesn't ever expose you to the notion of *threads*.  The one thing you cannot ever ignore when you write a DataReceived event handler.  So sure, you are having problems.  We don't know what they look like when you don't post your code.

Comment: Great question severely hampered by a lack of code. As it stands, this question is impossible to answer. Voting to close.

Comment: Added some code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not understand completely what you are meaning with the "DataReceived" and the "loop". I am also working a lot with Serial Ports as well as other interfaces. In my application I am attaching to the DataReceived Event and also reading based on the Bytes to read, but I dont use a loop there:

```
int bytesToRead = this._port.BytesToRead;
var data = new byte[bytesToRead];
this._port.BaseStream.Read(data , 0, bytesToRead);
```

If you are using a loop to read the bytes I recommend something like:

```
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(...);
```

Otherwise the Thread you are using to read the bytes is busy all the time. And this will lead to the fact that other threads cannot be processed or your CPU is at 100%.

But I think you don't have to use a loop for polling for the data if you are using the DataReceived event. If my undertanding is not correct or you need further information please ask.

Comment: Don't Thread.Sleep. Use async methods to read from the `SerialPort.BaseStream`.

Comment: I agree with you, Thread.Sleep is not a good way. Async methods are sure one of the better ways, but in his post he is asking why his CPU is going up to 100%. I tried to explained why.

Comment: Added some coding examples to clarify what i meant. To me it is important for the the method reading the serial port, to wait for delayed elements coming from the Xbee Node ( Which communicates via serial) to process the frame that comes in API mode from it. So it is vital for me to keep additional data a possibility if the frame is incomplete so the method processing the data can opt to wait a little for additional bytes or discard the frame.

Comment: Why dont you implement something like a buffer, where you add at first all data when you receive the message from the serial port via DataReceived Event. After adding, the second thread can check e.g. if the buffer contains a complete message and process further. I implemented something similar and recommend to do this logic in a seperate buffer then the buffer of the serial port.

Comment: My very first approach was something like you mentioned, user131210, but then i began to wonder what would happen if the stream kept being flooded continuously? Would i ever be out of the DataRead() Method ? Of course this is just a "What if" situation, but i wanted to take that into consideration.

Comment: Until know I did not focused any problems with my approach even when I get big amount of data. If you are getting alot of data, you can also specify the ReceivedBytesThreshold. With this property you can e.g. decide "how often" compared to the data that is comming in , the event is raised. In addition if you are using "producer" and "consumer" threads to process data, please take a look at the BlockingCollection. Very good synchronization regarding threads, better then booleans and while-loops. Just take it in consideration.

Comment: I will look for the topic, thanks for your input. I think that for the sake of getting this Academic project done, and because of my limited c# knowledge i might as well go with what you suggested on your 3rd response and ignore the scenario of endless stream of data.  

To recreate said Scenario i made a PIC send 2 correct api frames with a spacing of 1ms in between, in an infinite while loop. With the double threaded solution i wrote about in the question i had no problem to process it, but my CPU was suffering.

Comment: Your answer helped me. Using thread sleep actually mitigated the CPU usage problem. I was reading this book i took from the library: Learning C# 3.0 and during an explanation of delegates and events using a Clock class that constantly updated time information. it explained how the class couldn't be constantly updating the time or else the CPU would be tied to that process only, hence they used a small time out of 100 milliseconds. Thanks alot!